# Can I read email inbox from my Unity app?

Tags: c#, email, unity-game-engine

I am developing an app with Unity3d and I would like to be able to read the inbox of an email someone@example.com, I already managed to send mails from my unity app, but I couldn't find somewhere online a solution to reading the inbox of the mail

Answer (score 1):

You can implement POP or IMAP protocol yourself by following the spec documentation, depending what the email provider supports.

Or you can search codeplex/github/nuget/asset store for a C# POP or IMAP client.  I found this one pretty quickly.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit